# Help with p.m.f and p.g.f question.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, generating-functions

So we have the following question.

$Y$ is a discrete r.v with the positive integers as values. The p.m.f. of $Y$ is of the form:

$P(Y=k) = c \cdot \frac{1}{k!}, k = 1,2...$

a) what is the value of c?

$U_1, U_2, \dots$ are I.I.D r.v.s with $U_i \epsilon U(0,1)$ $U_1, U_2,...$are also independent of Y.

b) Set

$M = max(U_1, U_2, ..., U_Y)$

Show that for any $t$ in the interval $[0,1]$

$P(M\le t) = g_y(t)$

where $g_y(t)$ is the p.g.f. of $Y$.

---

So what I've done is calculated the c using the sum of p.m.f = 1 i.e.

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_x(k) = 1$

so

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty c \cdot \frac{1}{k!} = 1$

$c \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$ = $c ([\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}] -1)$

this gives

$c = \frac{1}{e-1}$

Now for the b) part I first calculate the p.g.f:

$g_y(t) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty t^k \cdot \frac{1}{e-1} \frac{1}{k!}$

$= \frac{1}{e-1} ([\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}] - 1)$

$= \frac{e^t - 1}{e -1}$

Now this is where i get uncertain. I then compare to $P(M \le t)$ which is due to independence:

$P(M \le t) = P(Max(U_1, U_2, ..., U_Y) \le t) = \prod_{i=1}^Y P(U_i \le t)$

As $U_i \epsilon U(0,1)$ we get $P(U_i \le t) = t and Therefore:

$\prod_{i=1}^Y P(U_i \le t) = t^Y$

Which is not the same as $g_y(t)$.

Can anyone explain where my reasoning is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, $P(M\le t\mid Y)=t^Y$ hence $P(M\le t)=E(t^Y)=g_Y(t)$.

Comment: Thanks,can you evaluate ? Why would i want to compare to $P(M \le t | Y)$ instead of $P(M \le t)$? And how do you get from $P(M \le t | Y)$ to $P(M \le t) = E(t^Y)$

Comment: Because the exercise describes $P(M\le t\mid Y)$ and because $E(P(M\le t\mid Y))=P(M\le t)$.

Comment: One more question why is $P(M \le t | Y) = P(M \le t) $. Does putting a conditional probability in expecation always remove the condition?

Comment: No, P(M≤t|Y)is not P(M≤t) but yes, E(P(M≤t|Y))=P(M≤t), which is a general property of conditional expectatons: for every event A and random variable Z, E(P(A|Z))=P(A). Which text on conditional expectation are you following?

Comment: It is because, in this particular case (which is an example of the general case): $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\mathsf P(M\leq t\mid Y)) & = \sum_{y\in\Bbb Z^+} \mathsf P(M\leq t\mid Y=y)\mathsf P(Y=y) & \text{by definition}\\ & = \sum_{y\in\Bbb Z^+} P(M\leq t\cap Y=y) \\ & = P(M\leq t\cap \bigcup_{y\in\Bbb Z^+} (Y=y)) \\ & = \mathsf P(M\leq t) & \text{by total probability theorem}\end{align}$$

Comment: The only text we have for our course is lecturenotes provided by our teacher. http://www.math.kth.se/matstat/gru/sf2940/lectnotemat2.pdf

I'll read through the part about conditional expectation w.r.t random variable again. Thanks!

And Thanks alot Graham Kemp.

Lol to bad you answered in the comment field is there any way to mark the question as solved when there are only comments? Thanks a lot you two!